# How to convert docx to pdf given the path in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

If I have a path like below, I want to convert the docx file to a pdf file.

```
C:\mywork\testsite\files\myfile.docx
```

How is it possible for me to do so in drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Drupal Convert File](https://github.com/delphian/drupal-convert-file) module for D7, but it doesn't look very supported. If this is for a low volume of files, I'd suggest using an external converter like [SmallPDF](https://smallpdf.com/).

You might also want to take a look at the [Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module, which turns Drupal objects into PDFs and could be a possible solution.